# "Undefined control sequence." for equation

Tags: errors, compilation-error

Latex compiles my code and it produces the PDF. But, I can not resolve the following error it gives me.

```
l.252 ...times   I\textsubscript{tx} \times \dfrac
                                                  
{B\textsubscript{tx}}{\del...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Following is the part of my code that shows this error.

```
\begin{equation}
E = E\textsubscript{s} + V\textsubscript{tx} \times   I\textsubscript{tx} \times \dfrac{B\textsubscript{tx}}{\delta\textsubscript{tx}} + V\textsubscript{sl} \times  I\textsubscript{sl} \times (T\textsubscript{b} - T\textsubscript{tx}) + E\textsubscript{rx} + E\textsubscript{o}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Are you loading the `amsmath` package?

Comment: I did not use that package. Using this package solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: May I ask why you are using `\textsubscript` here?

Comment: @daleif I use it to subscript. You can have a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m29KV.png).

Comment: But is there a reason you're not doing `$E_s+V_{tx}\times...$`?  `\textsubscript` is for text in a subscript.  A math subscript can be gotten by `_`.  If you need a word in the subscript, then you could do `V_{\mathrm{tax}}` or `V_{\mathit{tax}}`.

Comment: Many many thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

your equation code did not result in errors for me

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        E = E\textsubscript{s} + V\textsubscript{tx} \times   I\textsubscript{tx} \times \dfrac{B\textsubscript{tx}}{\delta\textsubscript{tx}} + V\textsubscript{sl} \times  I\textsubscript{sl} \times (T\textsubscript{b} - T\textsubscript{tx}) + E\textsubscript{rx} + E\textsubscript{o}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not use \usepackage{amsmath}.

Comment: Which is why we're so big on questions including a MWE, so we can see what packages you're loading.